# Making an element in an ocaml list point to a new value

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, ml

New to O'Caml, and I was playing around with lists, my goal is to do add elements, and make the existing list element point to its new value, that is if I have [4;6;7] that same list should become [4;10;17]

here is what I have so far:

```
let rec summation l curr  =
match l with [] -> l
| (x::xs) -> curr = x + curr
            x = curr;(*make the element in the list point to curr*)
summation xs curr ;;
```

I hope to invoke this function like summation [5;4;2] 0 and I feel like it should work.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use mutation here? It might be easier to code if you return a new list instead.

Comment: @missingno how would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCaml lists are immutable. You can't change them. There are ways to work with mutable data in OCaml--lists *are* immutable, but if you insist you could work with a list of mutable values. However, one of the reasons to study OCaml is to learn to work with immutable data. So that's what I'd suggest initially.

When working with immutable data, instead of changing your data you return a new version of the data that is different in the way you require. If your data is changing more than a little bit, you might want to use trees rather than lists.

**Update**

Let's say I want to calculate a list containing the squares of the values of my input list. One way to do it would be like this:

```
let rec squarelist l =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> (h * h) :: squarelist t
```

In essence, this function constructs a new list (using the `::` operator) with the contents I want it to have. Usually you can use recursion to handle the tail of the list.

Your case is a little harder because you need to carry a cumulative sum. So you might need a helper function with an extra argument.

Comment: I read many readings on lists, and can't quite figure out how I'd be able to add to a list in that sort of recursive manner. Any readings you suggest to help me learn this?

Comment: You should think of calculating a *new* list `[4; 10; 17]` rather than changing the initial list so it has new contents. You can't change a list, it's immutable.

Comment: OK; let me do it that way, and I will post an update. Let me think.

Comment: I was able to solve mine, thanks to your helpful example and educating me on the fact that lists are immutable. I read a lot of literature on lists, but that one totally flew by me. One question I do have is, by the time the match []->[] occurs, the reason we return [] is because, frankly, we don't care since we've increased the value of each element in the list already?

Comment: A better way to think of it is that `[]` is the *correct answer* when the input list is an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeffrey's answer, here is the correct code for your case

```
let summation l =
  let rec sum (acc,s) = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | hd::tl -> let new_sum = hd+s in sum (new_sum::acc, new_sum) tl
  in 
  sum ([],0) l
```

Note that once you master the recursion and functional way, you should think about tail-recursive often, especially you don't mind some performance downgrading.

---

**Re to your comment:**

`in` always follows a let if necessary. Normally, we have `let A in B`, it means define something A in something B.

let in my code, in short it means `let sum (acc,s)... in sum ([],0) l`. I define a function which can used in the part after `in`.

`function` is a shortcut for `match`. If without `function`, I would write:

```
let rec sum (acc,s) l = 
    match l with
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | hd::tl -> let new_sum = hd+s in sum (new_sum::acc, new_sum) tl
```

I suggest you read https://realworldocaml.org/, it is the best so far and newest book on ocaml, very good and comprehensive. It is free and you also can buy from Amazon.

Getting into OCaml's work is quite hard in the beginning. Especially, you need to understand what is `functional way`, comparing to the `imperative way` (like Java)

Comment: I was following your code, up until the 'in' why the 'in' can you explain it to me in your codes context? and why do you say = function?!

Comment: I understand your algorithm, but this part blows me off, I can't even comprehend what you're doing there. "tl
  in 
  sum ([],0) l"

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan Yes, I understand your confusion as I was there before. I suggest you really follow https://realworldocaml.org/, every early chapter and step. While you learning, open utop and try. U will eventually understand